# BrickLink: Sell items as whole set and/or individual parts

Tags: bricklink

I want to sell some sets, minifigures, and multi-part parts (e.g. wheels that consist of tyre and rim)—further referred to as sets—that I'm willing to sell either as complete set or individual parts.

In BrickLink, is there an option to marks sets to be sold this way so that customers may find the whole set *and* the individual parts, but can *only buy one of both options?* If I would put the parts and the set into the invetory I would be risking that a customers orders more parts than I have (the set plus another part of that set). At best (but that's just nice to have) the set would automatically be splittet into parts after a customer buys one or more parts of the set.

Comment: "I would be risking that a customers orders more parts than I have" - That's the reason such option doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you are looking for doesn’t exactly exist, but you can approximate it by using Superlots. Let’s use the tire and rim example: you list these as individual parts but make them part of a superlot that contains both. If a buyer wants to buy just the tire, they cannot, because of the superlot, but you could put in a note on the lot saying that they can message you to break up the lot and purchase individually. The downside is that someone searching for the combination entry for the parts (what you called a ‘set’) but not for the individual parts will not find your store.

Alternatively, you can list both (set and individual parts) and split the available amount across both (so if you have 6 tire and rim combos, you list 3 tires, 3 rims and 3 tire-and-rim sets) with a note on each saying that you have more available upon request. You can occasionally adjust quantities of each as you sell through them. Again, there is a search downside: if someone is looking for 4 tires and is excluding partial lots, they might not find your store.

Final alternative is just to commit to one or the other (I suggest based on the sales volume in the price guide) and see where that gets you.

If it makes any difference, I typically search for both the combo part and the individual parts, so I would find your store regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess together with TheBrickBlogger's answer this describes good methods to deal with the problem. Unfortuntely one cannot mark two answers as correct so I have to think about which to mark. I'll wait another day in case another answer will be written ...

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is more "in BrickLink" than TheBrickBlogger's. But both are useful.

Answer (score 2):

The specific feature you're asking doesn't exist. However, you can make notes on your set listings and say that you're willing to part out the set.

In addition, there are sophisticated tools for buyers to create wanted lists and check which sellers have all or most of the parts they need. So, if for example, they are looking for several parts from the same set, sellers who have those parts will automatically show up for them. Sellers don't have to do anything extra besides listing the parts to have this feature active.

Based on my personal experience as a BrickLink seller, my suggestion would be to list the sets you have for a few months (sets sell well during the Christmas season, so you may want to list it until the end of the year). Then, if they doesn't sell, part them out and sell the parts individually.

Also, consider listing the sets on eBay. In general, sets sell quicker and for more than on eBay. eBay buyers are more casual LEGO fans and are usually looking for gift items, sets from their childhood, etc.. BrickLink buyers are more project-focused, and they are looking for specific parts for their custom projects and not whole sets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess together with Phil B.'s answer this describes good methods to deal with the problem. Unfortuntely one cannot mark two answers as correct so I have to think about which to mark. I'll wait another day in case another answer will be written ...